# Redirecting unzip output to wp db import

Tags: mysql, wordpress, bash

I need to redirect the output of unzipping a file to a `wp db import`.

I found several solutions for piping unzip output to the mysql command, but they don't work with wp-cli. Sample for `mysql`:

```
gzip -c foo.sql.gz | mysql [args]
```

This fails for `wp db import` with the following error:

```
gzip -c foo.sql.gz | wp db import
Error: Import file missing: mydbname.sql
```

The problem seem to be that in the absence of a specific import file `wp db import` will look for a file with the name of your current db. It doesn't seem to accept the output from a pipe, nor does it accept what ought to be the output filename:

```
gzip -c foo.sql.gz | wp db import foo
Error: Import file missing: foo
```

...

```
gzip -c foo.sql.gz | wp db import foo.sql
Error: Import file missing: foo.sql
```

I don't know enough about imports, exports, stout and stin to fix this. I'd prefer to avoid creating a temp file because of clutter, and I'd prefer to use wp-cli over mysql because this is in a bash script that could run on any Wordpress site. I've tried using various iterations of gunzip, cat, gcat, and gzip on the left side of the pipe, but I suspect the issue is on the right side of the pipe. I've also tried this with redirecting `>` instead of pipe `|`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

wp_db_import reads from STDIN when - is used:

```
gzip -c -d foo.sql.gz | wp db import -
```

or try variations thereof with STDIN.

Comment: Fails for me:

    `$ gzip -c trnn_latest_6-23-15.sql.gz | wp db import -`
    `ERROR 1064 (42000) at line 1: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ?U' at line 1`

Comment: It's valid SQL. I can unzip  trnn_latest_6-23-15.sql.gz and import it with `wp db import  trnn_latest_6-23-15.sql`

Comment: The -d was it! Duh. =)

Comment: Note this works great on OSX 10.10. On 10.8, it fails with the error `sh: -: no such file or directory.`